# Angular HttpClient receive and handle 302/307response code; disable redirect

Tags: angular, angular7

I have the following service for my component:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MyService {
    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient ) { }
}
someFunction() {
   this.httpClient.post(url, data, options)
}
```

I also have a `HttpInterceptor` like below:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor() {}

  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req).do(
      (event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
          console.log('############### event status: ', event.status);
        }
        console.log('########### event is: ', event);
      },
      (err: any) => {
        if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
          console.log('HTTP error status is: ', err.status);
        } 
        console.log('error is: ', err);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Now, the post call that I have may receieve three types of response codes, either a `200` or a `302` or `307`. Now in cases where I get `200` everything works fine. However, when I get `302` or `307`, the default `HttpClient` keeps on following the `Location` in the response instead of giving me the control. The redirect url is a refresh url but it needs a different type of handling (`GET` instead of `POST` and some extra params added).

In case of errors like `400` I correctly get the error in my `Interceptor` catch block.

Is there a way to disable the HTTP redirect and handle the redirection in my code ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taken from [Mozilla docs: HTTP response status codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status):

> HTTP response status codes indicate whether a specific HTTP request has been successfully completed. Responses are grouped in five classes:
>
> Informational responses (100–199),
>
> Successful responses (200–299),
>
> **Redirects (300–399),**
>
> **Client errors (400–499),**
>
> **and Server errors (500–599).**

As you can see, `3xx` HTTP status codes are ***NOT*** errors but redirects. Only `4xx` and `5xx` HTTP Status codes are considered as *error responses*. This is why when your angular app received  a `4xx` response, your interceptor's catch block correctly handled it.

---

Taken from [Mozilla docs: Redirections in HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections):

> #### Principle
>
> In HTTP, a redirection is triggered by the server by sending special responses to a request: redirects. HTTP redirects are responses with a status code of 3xx. **A browser, when receiving a redirect response, uses the new URL provided and *immediately loads it***: most of the time, the redirection is transparent to the user, besides a small performance hit.

Unfortunately, when browsers received a `3xx` response, they take the initiative and immediately requests for the URI defined in the `Location` header. Therefore, there isn't a way for you to intercept the response and do something with it.

---

If the API is your own, it'd be easier for you to simply change it to return a different HTTP status code. You had mentioned the 302 returns a "refresh url". If you are using JWT and you are trying to refresh tokens, then it'd be easier to return a `400: BAD REQUEST` or `401: UNAUTHORIZED` and let your interceptor's error block handle call the refresh url.

If the API is someone else's, then, consider changing your Angular app design/app flow to handle the redirect response.

Comment: "If the API is someone else's, then, consider changing your Angular app design/app flow to handle the redirect response."
how to do this?